# Flutter screen recording

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video, screen-recording

Hi Im trying to record a screen because I don't find a way to add an overlay to the camera video save.

I tried many plugin flutter_screen_recording, screen_capture_event, device_screen_recorder and screen_recorder but I didn't find a way to make them work properly. I chosen screen recording but if you have a solution to add the overlay in the camera video i take it too.

Thanks.

EDIT: For more informations the plugin flutter_screen_recording work fine on ios but not on android

Comment: This is not the correct type of question for StackOverflow. Users will help you fix your code, not answer open ended questions.
You should try exploring solutions unrelated to Flutter. To record the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is Package for Screen Recording in flutter called `flutter_screen_recording`

You can try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i already tried this plugin but it crash when i start the record

Comment: once clear the cache and clean the code and try it once again. I didn't face any issue with this Plugin. Make it right it was working for me.